# Exchange emails not delivering for one user

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003

We have an Exchange infrastructure going through a migration from 2003 SP2 (call it `ExOld`) to 2010 (`ExNew`).

All users are now on the new server, but mail is still being directed to `ExOld` until testing is complete. `ExNew` sends emails directly to the internet.

For one particular user, emails don't seem to be being reliably delivered, but the odd thing is that it's not all emails. I can see external emails in his inbox.

- If I send an internal email it works fine.
- If I send an email from Gmail to him it doesn't get through.
- If I telnet from outside to `ExOld` I can send an email to him.
- If I telnet from outside to `ExNew` I can send an email to him.

This is a transcript that results in a successful send:

```
    220 ExOldName Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready at  Mon, 22 Oct 2012 10:55:26 +0100
    EHLO test.com
    500 5.3.3 Unrecognized command
    EHLO test.com
    250-ExOldFQDN Hello [MyTestExternalIp]
    250-TURN
    250-SIZE
    250-ETRN
    250-PIPELINING
    250-DSN
    250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
    250-8bitmime
    250-BINARYMIME
    250-CHUNKING
    250-VRFY
    250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN
    250-X-EXPS=LOGIN
    250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN
    250-AUTH=LOGIN
    250-X-LINK2STATE
    250-XEXCH50
    250 OK
    MAIL FROM:me@external.domain
    250 2.1.0 me@external.domain...Sender OK
    RCPT TO:his@internal.ourdomain notify=success,failure
    250 2.1.5 his@internal.ourdomain 
    DATA
    354 Start mail input; end with .
    Subject:Test 1056
    Test 10:56
    .
    250 2.6.0  Queued mail for delivery
    quit
    221 2.0.0 ExOldFQDN Service closing transmission channel
```

Emails go through Symantec Cloud, but their "Track and Trace" shows the messages going through, with a "delivered ok" log entry.

```
2012-10-22 09:19:56 Connection from: 209.85.212.171 (mail-wi0-f171.google.com)
2012-10-22 09:19:56 Sending server HELO string:mail-wi0-f171.google.com
2012-10-22 09:19:56 Message id:CAE5-_4hzGpY2kXFbzxu7gzEUSj5BAvi+BB5q1Gjb6UUOXOWT3g@mail.gmail.com
2012-10-22 09:19:56 Message reference: 135089759500000177171130001194006
2012-10-22 09:19:56 Sender: me@external.domain
2012-10-22 09:19:56 Recipient: his@internal.ourdomain
2012-10-22 09:20:26 SMTP Status: OK
2012-10-22 09:19:56 Delivery attempt #1 (final)
2012-10-22 09:19:56 Recipient server: ExOldIP (ExOldIP)
2012-10-22 09:19:56 Response: 250 2.6.0 Queued mail for delivery
```

I've tried to search the Message Tracking Center on `ExOld`, but I just get the following message:

> The tracking database on ExOld.FQQN is not available or the message has left the Exchange organisation. Facility: Microsoft Exchange Management ID no: c1032751 Microsoft Exchange Management

I'm not sure where else to look on the old (or new) server for information as to where the mails are ending up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be the dumbest question as I'm pretty sure you've already checked, but, what does Exchange Message Tracker say on ExOld?  Does the server say it ever got to that mailbox?

Comment: Not a daft question - I've not had to hunt down rogue messages much before (not since 5.5!) so any clue will be a help.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/The_Exchange_Message_Tracking_Center_or_How_to_Save_Your_A_in_a_Pinch.html

Comment: That was it - I didn't have tracking enabled. Of course now the emails seem to be coming in to him, so I'll just leave it on and kind of hope another one fails.